# How to keep a track of loggedin user in jsf 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 framework and I need help. To put it as simple as I can, what I need is to get a user's `username` and id and display it in the application I'm building.

This is my UserBean class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScope
 public class UserBean implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private int id;
 private String username;
 private String password;
 //getter and setter methods
```

At the `index.xhtml` page, the user needs to enter the username and password in order to login(comparing values from database). When he does, I want to output his username and id on the next page and keep track of that throughout whole application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257941/jsf-header-with-login-component

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as username  and id are in the session scoped bean. you can get them from the session map like this.

page2.XHTML

```
<h:outputText value="#{page2Bean.uname}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{page2Bean.id}"/>


Page2Bean.java
@managedBean(name="page2Bean")
class Page2Bean {
private String uName;
private int id;
//getters and setters 
public page2Bean() {
UserBean uBean = (UserBean)     (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()).get("userBean"));// get the UserBean which is in the session
 this.uName= uBean.getUserName();
this.id= uBean.getId();

}
```

**EDIT**
you get the session data (username and id in this case) in the constructor and assign them to your attributes which you use in your page2.xhtml

lemme know if it helps...

Comment: ok, and how do i get them in let's say page2.xhtml(a page where user is redirected after sucessfull login)?

Comment: i don't want to trouble you, but i don't quite know how to implement this.. Ok, i understand the whole "FacesContext" concept, but don't really know how to use it. The way accesing the beans username is ok, but in which class, method do i make FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()) thing? Is it a constructor of a userBean class, is it a new class... I'm really sorry if you don't quite understand what i'm saying, i'm a little confused right now...

Comment: see the edit, yes you can get the session data in the constructor as in the above code

Comment: yes, i understand now... just, it doesn't display it in my case... with "get("userBean") i am accessing the UserBean bean, am i right?

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserBean` is **already** in the session scope. You don't need to "keep track" of it yourself at all. If you need to display the properties of an arbitrary JSF managed bean in the view, just access them in EL the usual way.

```html
<p>Welcome, #{userBean.username}!</p>
```

If you need to inject it in other beans, because you need the user's information in postconstructor or (action)listener methods, then just use `@ManagedProperty`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OtherBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{userBean}")
    private UserBean userBean; // +setter

    // ...
 }
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Comment: Functionally no, designtechnically yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get session data form page directly. Use as below.

```
   <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.UserBean.username}"/>
   <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.UserBean.id}"/>
```

Comment: when i try this, i only get sessionScope.userBean and that's all.. It doesn't offer any field to access it after that! I get the whole concept of accessing beans with EL, but i don't really know how to use and implement it in my situation....

Comment: Please don't focus too much on IDE autocomplete as "the right answer", for sure not when you're working with EL.